# How to extract text from xhr.responseText and insert the text in textarea?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**xhr.responseText** Is in such a form:

```
responseText: "{11111111.gif}[\"24\\/200523\\/q5ec91d184ab9a.webp\",\"24\\/200523\\/M5ec91d18992ce.webp\"]"
```

**[ ]** It may be empty, or there may be more.
If empty, Is in such a form:

```
responseText: "{11111111.gif}[]"
```

How to extract and insert the extracted data in textarea like as:

```
24/200523/q5ec91d184ab9a.webp
24/200523/M5ec91d18992ce.webp
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. My problem already solved with help the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61972846/3146610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple regex to retrieve everything between [] including square brackets and then `JSON.parse` it

```
let files = responseText.match(/\[.*\]/);
files = JSON.parse(files);
```

Now you have an array with these files (or an empty array if there were no data) and you can make it a string with `.join` method.

```
files = files.join('\n');
```